# Unix Date Arithmetic

Tags: file, datetime, unix, aix

Env: AIX 6.1

I have a requirement to find the modified timestamp of the latest file in a directory, and subtract a parameterized time value like a few seconds or minutes from it, and then create a reference file with the resultant timestamp with "touch -t".

This file will be used to scan the directory at a later point of time, for any newer files than the reference file created, using the "find -newer" command.

Can someone help me do this?

1. Find the modified timestamp of a file?
2. Subtract a few seconds or minutes, provided as parameter to the script in the form (MM.SS or just SS) from the above timestamp.
3. The result has to be in the form YYMMDDhhmm.ss to be able to create the reference file with the "touch -t" command.

Following is the approach I tried.

1. I found the modified timestamp of a file with the following command.
   perl -e '@d=localtime ((stat(shift))[9]); printf "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d.%02d\n", $d[5]+1900,$d[4]+1,$d[3],$d[2],$d[1],$d[0]'

Output is in the format YYMMDDhhmi.ss

2. From the above timestamp, I subtracted 30 secs for example as below.
   print "${latest_file_ts}-${P_TS_ADJ}"| bc
3. With the output of above step, following touch command has been used.

touch -t "YYMMDDDhhmi.ss"

This file that has been created, will be used at a later point of time with 
"find  -type f -newer  to find all files newer than it in the directory.

However, the ""${latest_file_ts}-${P_TS_ADJ}"| bc" isn't working correctly, since I am performing numeric arithmetic and not date arithmetic.

So, I am getting wrong results after subtraction. Can you help resolve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: How about using helper tools like [dateutils' `datediff`](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#datediff)?